# Reuse Windows Service classes

Tags: asp.net, windows, web-services

I have a ASP Net project of the type Windows Service.

When I build that project an exe file is generated.

Now I also have another project os the type Web Service, that uses classes from the previous Windows Service project.

When I build the Web Service, on it's bin/debug folder, the Windows Service exe is there, instead of a DLL.

This way, when I deploy the Web Service on ISS, I get an exception when the part of the code that instatiates a class on the Windows Service project is executed.

The only whay I found to solve this issue, is to make the output type of the Windows Service to DLL instead of EXE, and the Web Service runs correctly.

But, of course, when I try to install the Windows Service, I get this error:

[image]

Can I even do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Services and web services are different project types. You cannot run the same executable. You have to options:

1. Either you put the common code into a class library and create a project for the windows service and one for the webservice
2. You create to build targets.

Option 1 seems to be easier for me

Comment: Just for the record, these are completelly separate projects.

What I did was that on the Web Service project I added a reference to the Windows Service project.

Comment: But you can normally not reference an excecutable, only libraries. And web projects are always compiled as a library. As I said, I would put the common code into a dll.

Comment: Do you want to start the windows service from the web application? That doesn't work either

Comment: Put the common classes on a class library... Thanks